# Take a phone screenshot vs an app screenshot

Tags: java, android, screenshot

I'm trying to take a system screenshot in an app (for instance, if I minimize the app, I want to be able to have the screenshot of what's being shown on the screen, not a screeshot of the app itself).

I think I'm using the wrong view at this point.  Below are some of the views I've tried

```
//View v1 = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
//Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

I think I'm pretty close to getting what I'm looking for but I can't seem to figure out what view I should be using (or maybe I'm using the wrong approach altogether).

If anyone has any ideas of how to do this, please let me know!  I'm guessing it's going to be one line of code but I'm not sure what line that might be . . .

Thanks!

Comment: `getWindow()` runs in the context of the loaded app... Sounds like a security flaw if "minimized apps" could screenshot views outside of themselves (not just the launcher, but other apps, as well, which could have sensitive information)

Comment: @OneCricketeer So does this mean this wouldn't be possible?  There are apps like ScrCpy that take screenshots but maybe they do it via ADB?

Comment: Haven't used it [but looks like adb is a requirement](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) for it to work, so makes sense.

Comment: services similar to ScrCpy can do this ONLY via USB. there is also a [Vysor](https://www.vysor.io/) service, in addition it also works in web browser. but only in Chrome, as it supports WebUSB. because USB is needed for ADB, you know... Btw. that would be a HUGE waste of resources if Android OS would "draw" backgrounded apps, I'm pretty shure it isn't. Or maybe you want screenshot of anything what is shown on screen? take a look on `MediaProjection` and/or `AccessibilityService` classes

Comment: "I'm guessing it's going to be one line of code" -- probably not. As shachmsm states, probably what you are looking for is `MediaProjection`. See "The Media Projection APIs" chapter in [this free older book of mine](https://commonsware.com/Android/).

Comment: Yeah, I guess I was optimistic that I just had to load the correct view.  What both of you pointed out makes sense.  That might be the route to go but I might take a completely different approach at my problem if this looks like it's going to severely complicate it.  Well, at least I know the limitations.  Thanks for your help!